# .replace "</div>" in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string as following:

```
this is an example of </div>
```

Then using `.replace`, I want to get replace `</div>` with something else.

```
content.replace(/</div>/g,'function'); //remove </div>
```

However, the "/" inside of bracket is causing an error. How would I fix this?

Comment: `content.replace(/<\/div>/g,'function'); //remove </div>`

Comment: Ah, Thanks! Of course. =)

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the slash.  Try something like this:

```
content.replace(/<\/div>/g,'');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the `/` (using backslash `\/`):

```
content.replace(/<\/div>/g,'function'); //remove </div>
```

or you can create a new RegExp object:

```
r = new RegExp('</div>', 'g')
```